# Does MS Project provide a way of opening the Task Information window?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am trying to open the "Task information" window via MSProject 2010 InterOp. Is the function available in the Object Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [InformationDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/office.vbapj.chm217(v=office.14).aspx) method opens the task information window for the selected task